# Xamarin-iOS - Failed to spawn AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent on IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I'm getting the below error when doing a build:

Building solution {app} (Debug|iPhoneSimulator) Build started 15/07/2022 9:01:56 a.m..
__________________________________________________ Project "{project_folder}/{app}.iOS.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target _DetectDebugNetworkConfiguration: DebugIPAddresses: 127.0.0.1 Target _BeforeCoreCompileImageAssets: Removing directory "obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool". Target _DetectSigningIdentity: Detected signing identity:
Bundle Id: {app_id} App Id: {app_id} Target _CoreCompileImageAssets: Tool /usr/bin/xcrun execution started with arguments: actool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format xml1
--output-partial-info-plist {project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/partial-info.plist
--app-icon AppIcons --compress-pngs --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 12.4 --platform iphonesimulator --compile {project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/bundle {project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets
Tool /usr/bin/xcrun execution finished (exit code = 1).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.actool.compilation-results</key>
    <dict>
        <key>output-files</key>
        <array>
            <string>{project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/bundle/AppIcons60x60@2x.png</string>
            <string>{project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/bundle/AppIcons76x76@2x~ipad.png</string>
            <string>{project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/partial-info.plist</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>com.apple.actool.errors</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>description</key>
            <string>Failed to launch AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent via CoreSimulator spawn</string>
            <key>failure-reason</key>
            <string>Failed to spawn AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent on IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (28A1575F-0FE4-4775-8754-374E267B4808, (null), Shutdown)</string>
            <key>underlying-errors</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>Invalid device: The specified device is not available for spawning processes.</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

2022-07-15 09:01:58.547 ibtoold[2634:43203] DEBUG: Added to environment: {  TMPDIR = "/var/folders/bq/w_n35lts0hg9t6r5_ww_662h0000gr/T/4E1AC64D-4836-4CAF-BF0D-41792442AAD7"; }
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : /usr/bin/xcrun exited with code 1
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error :
{project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets : error : 2022-07-15 09:01:58.547 ibtoold[2634:43203] DEBUG: Added to environment: {
{project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets : error :     TMPDIR = "/var/folders/bq/w_n35lts0hg9t6r5_ww_662h0000gr/T/4E1AC64D-4836-4CAF-BF0D-41792442AAD7";
{project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets : error : }
{project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets : error :
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : actool exited with code 1
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error :
{project_folder}/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets : actool error : Failed to launch AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent via CoreSimulator spawn Done building target "_CoreCompileImageAssets" in project "{app}.iOS.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "{app}.iOS.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Any ideas on why and/or how to fix this?

Comment: I'd guess something corrupted. Reboot, make sure both xcode and visual studio are latest versions, delete your project's `bin` and `obj` folders. OR maybe there is a bad asset - remove all assets, add them back. **If still fails,** download sources from your source repo to a **new folder**, and build there. [To break any "cache" dependencies.] If even that fails, create a new xamarin.ios project, make sure that builds, then transfer source files to it. Alternative possibility (unlikely): something corrupted - delete and reinstall visual studio.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when building newly created blank Multiplatform (Xamarin.Forms)/iOS apps. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio and XCode a few times and the error is still present.

Comment: Have you run xcode itself recently?  If not, run it. Wait 30 seconds. Sometimes after xcode updates or visual studio updates, there is an update to "additional components" that is needed. If so, it will pop up a msg box asking if you want to install them. I don't think that can cause what you are seeing, but worth a check.